# Store boolean using sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I added a library to show 'feature discovery' when the app is first launched to show a target prompt in my app and its working perfect except for the fact that once the user exits the app, it shows again.  I know I need to store it in sharedpreferences but I'm not entirely sure how (and my google searches haven't helped much).  My code is as follows:

```
    new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTarget(findViewById(R.id.fab))
            .setPrimaryText("Write your first note")
            .setSecondaryText("Tap the icon to start composing your first note")
            .setOnHidePromptListener(new MaterialTapTargetPrompt.OnHidePromptListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onHidePrompt(MotionEvent event, boolean tappedTarget)
                {
                    //Do something such as storing a value so that this prompt is never shown again
                    if (tappedTarget)
                        return;

                }

                @Override
                public void onHidePromptComplete() {

                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

The issue I'm having is in the **onHidePrompt** method, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mike-m Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Apparently my googling skills need some work.

Comment: They're much easier to find when you already know the titles. :-) Cheers!